# Why is an object sent into this function, but is never used?

Tags: c++

```
int height(const Tree& T, const Position& p) {
    if (p.isExternal()) return 0;       // leaf has height 0
    int h = 0;
    PositionList ch = p.children();     // list of children
    for (Iterator q = ch.begin(); q != ch.end(); ++q)
      h = max(h, height(T, *q));
    return 1 + h;               // 1 + max height of children
  }
```

My textbook gives the above code for finding the height of a general tree. Why is "Tree T" sent into the function if it is never used (its member functions/variables never called or used) throughout the function?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Recursion.

Comment: @chris only if `*q` is of type `Position`...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Yeah, I'm thinking of corner cases. It *is* a `PositionList` iterator, though.

Comment: Which it probably is, yes :)

Comment: It's going to return the max from T or *q everytime the recursion call height. You have to know that this function must use this T to compare.

Comment: @user1824518: height() is a recursive function .. and you're right, "T" doesn't seem to be used anywhere.  In other words - a complete waste of time and space ;)  Also: I'm extremely suspicious of "h"...

Comment: So T is more of a "label"? To keep it clear that you're finding the height of a node in T?

Comment: @user1824518: The code does not look very clean. For example, the child list appears to be *copied* into `ch` (assuming that `PositionList` is a non-reference type) for no reason whatsoever, which is a clear sign of poorly written code. Taking that into account it is quite possible that the author added that `T` parameter by mistake: originally they thought it might be needed, but failed to notice that it is not.

Comment: is `Tree` a dependent type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is for some sort of consistency with other functions. For example, a function `depth` might calculate the depth of a position by starting at the root of the tree and using DFS to find that position.